# Removing Punctuation and Capitalization from TXT file

Tags: python

I've got a minor problem in python. 
I have the script:

```
import nltk
def analyzer():
    inputfile=raw_input("Which file?: ")
    review=open(inputfile,'r')
    review=review.read()
    tokens=review.split()

    for token in tokens:
        if token in string.punctuation:         
            tokens.remove(token)
        token=tokens.lower()
```

It is supposed to import a txt file, split it in words and then remove punctuation and convert all to lowercase. Shouldn't be difficult, right? It just returns still with the punctuation and the uppercase intact. There is no error message, it just seems to ignore part of the code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you expecting it to change the original file? Because you're not writing the changes anywhere...

Comment: no, I intend to do a lot more with the string in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several problems in your code:

First, `split()` could not split punctuations

Second, if you use `for token in tokens`, `token` is actually a copy of the elements in `tokens` so changement on `token` wouldn't change `tokens`.

Try this:

```
import string
import re
def analyzer():
    inputfile=raw_input("Which file?: ")
    review=open(inputfile,'r')
    review=review.read()
    tokens=[e.lower() for e in map(string.strip, re.split("(\W+)", review)) if len(e) > 0 and not re.match("\W",e)]

    print tokens

analyzer()
```

The pattern `[FUNC(x) for x in LIST if COND]` gives out a list constructd by FUNC(x), where x is the element from LIST when COND is true. You could refer to [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). For the regex part you may look into [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a million, but can you explain exactly what the code does? As I really hate it to use code that I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have the `string` module imported. Replace the line

```
if token in string.punctuation:         
     tokens.remove(token)
     token=tokens.lower()
```

with

```
token = token.translate(None,string.punctuation).lower()
```

Also, strings are immutable in python so assigning to them just rebinds the name it does not change the original tokens. If you'd like to change the tokens then you can do the following

```
tokens = [token.translate(None,string.punctuation).lower() for token in tokens]
```

Personally I would clean up the whole thing like this:

```
def read_tokens(path):
    import string
    with open(path) as f:
        tokens = f.read().split()
        return [ token.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() for token in tokens ]

read_tokens(raw_input("which file?"))
```

Note that this is just a faithful translation of your original intentions which mean that a "word" like `'test.me'` would turn into `['testme']` rather than `['test','me']`

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

Comment: in which snippet? I did have a mistake in the 2nd one. I capitalized `string` but I've fixed that and your error sounds unrelated. And yes `translate` is a string method, not a list method. but it's called on a string in my example.

Comment: My code is now:
'code'
def analyzer():
    inputfile=raw_input("Which file?: ")
    review=open(inputfile,'r')
    review=review.read()
    tokens=review.split()
    tokens=[tokens.translate(None,String.punctuation).lower() for token in tokens] 'code'

And the error I get is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\Desktop\t2.py", line 55, in <module>
    analyzer()
  File "C:\Users\gebruiker\Desktop\t2.py", line 12, in analyzer
    tokens=[tokens.translate(None,String.punctuation).lower() for token in tokens]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

Comment: I posted a version of your code that works as you would expect it to.